# Solving a particular integro-differential equation: $g(x) = \int_1^x \frac{F(u)}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} \, du$

Tags: calculus, probability, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, integro-differential-equations

As the title says: I'm interested in the following integro-differential equation. Let $g:(1,\infty) \to [0,1]$ be given, and assume $g$ is smooth. I want to find functions $F:[1,\infty) \to [0,1]$ that satisfy:

i) For every $x \in (1, \infty)$, $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{F(u)}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} \, du = g(x)$

ii) $F$ is non-decreasing, right continuous, $F(1) = 0$, and $\lim_{y \to \infty} F(y) = 1$, i.e. $F$ is a CDF supported on $(1,\infty)$.

The first thing to try is differentiating, but this doesn't seem to go anywhere: since that the integrand $\frac{F(u)}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}}$ blows up at $u = x$, we can't (immediately) pass the derivative through the integral.

The next thing is integrating by parts, which yields

$\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} F(x) - \int_1^x F'(u) \arctan\Big(\frac{u}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}}\Big) \,du.$

(Some additional assumptions are needed here: for example, that $F$ is differentiable.) Now using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),

$\displaystyle g'(x) = \int_1^x \frac{F'(u)}{x\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} \, du.$

But this doesn't seem to help much.

Are there standard methods for this kind of thing? Is there some way to make sense of passing the derivative inside the integral?

I would be happy to see an example of some $g$ and $F$ that satisfy this: I have no such examples right now.

Comment: By adapting the functions and changing the integration variable, the problem is equivalent to [Abel equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ie/ie0105.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral equation \begin{equation}
 \int_1^x \frac{F(u)}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} \, du = g(x)
\end{equation} 
is a classical variant of the [Abel equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ie/ie0105.pdf): 
\begin{equation}
  f(s)=\int_1^s\frac{y(t)\,dt}{\sqrt{s-t}}
\end{equation}
which has a solution
\begin{equation}
 y(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{d}{dt}\int_1^t\frac{f(s)\,ds}{\sqrt{t-s}}
\end{equation} 
This result can be checked by pluging this solution in the integral equation.

Changing $t=u^2$ in the Abel integral equation, $2\sqrt{t}y(t)=F(u)$, $s=x^2$ and $f(s)=g(x)$, the problem is then
\begin{equation}
 g(x)=\int_1^x \frac{F(u)}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} \, du
\end{equation} 
its solution is
\begin{align}
\frac{F(u)}{2u}&=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{d}{dt}\int_1^t\frac{g(x)\,ds}{\sqrt{t-s}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{2u}\frac{d}{du}\int_1^u\frac{2xg(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{u^2-x^2}}
\end{align} 
and thus
\begin{equation}
 F(u)=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{d}{du}\int_1^u \frac{xg(x)}{\sqrt{u^2-x^2}}\,dx
\end{equation} 
Concerning now the requirement $F(1)=0$, one can show by expressing the derivative, that (see below), for $u\to 1$,
$$ F(u)\sim \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}g(u)(u-1)^{-1/2}$$ then the condition imposes $g(u)=o\left(\sqrt{u-1}\right)$.

As an example, taking $g(u)=\tfrac\pi2(u-a)$, we found
$$ F(u)=\frac{1}{u}\frac{u^2-a}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}$$
and thus $F(1)=0$ if $a=1$, i.e. when $g(1)=0$. Additionally, in this example, $\lim_{u\to\infty}F(u)=1$.

---

To evaluate the derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi}{2}F(u)=\frac{d}{du}\int_1^u\frac{xg(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{u^2-x^2}}
\end{equation} 
we first change the variable $x=uv$ to expressed
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2}F(u)&=\frac{d}{du}u\int_{\tfrac{1}{u}}^1\frac{tg(ut)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{u}\int_1^u\frac{xg(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{u^2-x^2}}+\frac{1}{u}\int_1^u\frac{x^2g'(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{u^2-x^2}}+\frac{1}{u}\frac{g(1)}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}
\end{align} 
Both integrals vanish when $u=1$, the last term $\sim \frac{g(1)}{\sqrt{2(u-1)}}$ when $u\sim 1$.